# What's the correct syntax for given mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Question: Write a MongoDB query to find the restaurants which locates in latitude value less than -95.754168.

Structure of 'restaurants' collection

```
{
"address": {
"building": "1007",
"coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
"street": "Morris Park Ave",
"zipcode": "10462"
},
"borough": "Bronx",
"cuisine": "Bakery",
"grades": [
{ "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
{ "date": { "$date": 1378857600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
{ "date": { "$date": 1358985600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
{ "date": { "$date": 1322006400000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
{ "date": { "$date": 1299715200000 }, "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
],
"name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
"restaurant_id": "30075445"
}
```

Author's Answer is : db.restaurants.find({"address.coord" : {$lt : -95.754168}});

Is this the correct answer?
If no then what is the correct answer?

Resource: http://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/#PracticeOnline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go into your `coord` index like this

```
db.restaurants.find({"address.coord.0" : {$lt: -95.754168}});
```

According to the documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation),

> > MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of an embedded document.
> >
> > E.g. `<array>.<index>`

Note that the index is 0-based.